# Remove conditionally "proceed to checkout" button from minicart in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce, cart

In woocommerce I am currently seeking to add a function in my theme's `functions.php` file, if two conditions are met. Then, using `elseif()`, deploy the function if only one condition is met.

The code is as follows:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_before_buttons' , 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );

function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
    $minimum = 150;
    $minimum2 = 100;

    if ( is_page([232]) && WC()->cart->subtotal < $minimum2 ) {
        if( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart' ) {
            wc_print_notice(
                sprintf( 'Your current order total does not meet the %s minimum' , 
                    wc_price( $minimum2 )
                ), 'error' 
            );
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons', 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );

        } 
        else {
            wc_add_notice( 
                sprintf( 'Your current order total does not meet the %s minimum' , 
                    wc_price( $minimum2 )
                ), 'error' 
            );
        }

    }
    elseif ( WC()->cart->subtotal < $minimum ) {
        if( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart' ) {
            wc_print_notice(
                sprintf( 'Your current order total does not meet the %s minimum', 
                    wc_price( $minimum )
                ), 'error' 
            );
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons', 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );

        } 
        else {
            wc_add_notice( 
                sprintf( 'Your current order total does not meet the %s minimum' , 
                    wc_price( $minimum )
                ), 'error' 
            );
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is hide the checkout button for the woocommerce widget if the minimum order amount is not met. However, different pages have different minimums.

I'm trying to hide the checkout button if the cart isn't equal to $150. But for one page in particular, I only want the cart to have a minimum of $100.

Comment: The main problem I can see (without testing, as I'm not at my desk right now) is `if( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart' ) {` - you're not actually testing anything in your if statement. What about the string 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart'  are you testing? What is it supposed to equal or not equal?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the hook that you are using is only made for minicart widget, so you don't need to test that in an `IF` statement.

You are making that much more complicated that it should be. Try the following revisited code instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_before_buttons' , 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
    $min_amount = is_page([232]) ? 100 : 150;

    if( WC()->cart->subtotal < $min_amount ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons', 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );

        wc_add_notice( 
            sprintf( 'Your current order total does not meet the %s minimum' , 
                wc_price( $min_amount )
            ), 'error' 
        );
    } 
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should better work now.

Comment: That is much cleaner, thank you very much. However, as you can see for the page/post 232 that is found at https://www.restaurantsonwheels.com/restaurants/rancho-viejo-mexican-food/   it won't activate the "checkout" button unless the minimum is above $150, not $100 as needed for this page....thank you for your help

Comment: @ThirsHuey Sorry I don't catch?  You need to be sure that is_page([232]) is working for you (and nobody can guess that)…